# Not able to create database dump from usb

Tags: php, usb, mysql

I am working on an application which need to run by USB. I am using Uniform Server to do this.

My Application is running properly but I am not able to create database dump using `System("MY COMMAND")`.
This is my php code.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date =date('d-m-y_h-i-s-A', time());
$fl = $date . "_backup.sql"; 
$query = "F:\\UniServerZ\\core\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --user root --password root " . $c['database'] . " > ../uploads/" . $fl . "";
system($query);
    echo '<a href="http://' . $_POST['loc'] . '/Rally/uploads/' . $fl . '" download="' . $fl . '">Click Here To Download Database Dump

                </a>';
```

I can perform this action on my wamp server but not able to do this by usb server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the solution 
We can create datadump in different ways (Can get ref from: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/mysql-database-backup-mysql-mysqldump-backup-command/)

In my case i used

```
 $query = "F:\\UniServerZ\\core\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe --user root --password=root " . $c['database'] . " > ../uploads/" . $fl . "";
```

This is working for me. :)